# Disable keypress on numbers greater than 3 digits

Tags: javascript, vue.js, input, keypress

I have this code, I would like to prevent the user from entering if the number of digits entered is greater than 3.
So if the user writes for example 150 it is fine, if he tries to write a number with 4 or more digits: such as 1601 then the code should prevent this.

**So it must disable the keypress.**

```html
<template>
  <b-form-input type="number" v-model="number" @input="getPeople(number)">
  </b-form-input>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        number: "",
      };
    },
    getPeople(text) {
      if (text.length >= 3) {
        text.preventDefault();
      }
    },
  };
</script>
```

As of right now the code doesn't work and here is what the error says:

```
 v-on handler: "TypeError: text.preventDefault is not a function"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best possible UI/UX is not to prevent the user from entering invalid data, but to tell them why it's invalid, when it is. If you're interested into why that's the case, it's a long discussion and this is probably not the best place to outline it. But it boils down to: treat your users with the maximum possible amount of respect. Disallowing typing contradicts that principle.

Getting back to your example, the basic way to handle it is using `max` attribute:

```
<b-form-input
  type="number"
  v-model="number"
  max="999"
  @input="getPeople(number)" />
```

If you want more control over how the validation message is displayed and when validation is triggered, you could use a validation plugin outlined in [BootstrapVue's documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/reference/validation) (since you use BV).

Note you'll need to update the markup to match the preferred validation plugin's requirements.

---

If you (or your client) really want(s) to call `preventDefault()` on the `input` event, according to [BV documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-input#native-and-custom-events)

> You can always access the native `input` and `change` events by using the `.native` modifier.

you will have to apply the `.native` modifier in order to get the native `event` as param. Otherwise you'll only get the `value`.

```
<b-form-input
  type="number"
  v-model="number"
  @input.native="getPeople" />
```

and modify `getPeople` to:

```
methods: {
  getPeople(event) {
    if (event.target.value >= 1e3) {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.number = 999;
    }
  }
}
```

See it working:

```js
let memory = 0;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    number: 0
  }),
  methods: {
    getPeople(event) {
      if (event.target.value >= 1e3) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.number = memory;
      } else {
        memory = event.target.value;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="//polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CIntersectionObserver"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="m-5">
  <b-form-input type="number" v-model="number" @input.native="getPeople" />
</div>
```

Comment: the first case you told me I can also consider, but in the second case you have practically given the same and identical solution that I found and I have already written in question that it does not work ... indeed it is totally wrong because if I do a console. log of "event.target.value" even tells me it's "undefined"

Comment: @luca88 It sounds like you have not changed the markup from `@input="getPeople(number)"` to `@input="getPeople"`. If what I posted doesn't help you, you might want to provide a *runnable* [mcve] so I could inspect it. We must be overlooking something and without being to inspect the actual code I can't help you any more than I already have.

Comment: but i believe this is already playable ... just start a new project in vue with bootstrap vue and paste my code it should already be working ... what are you missing?

Comment: @luca88, you might be right, but if the bug is due to something you haven't included I'll create a project and lose my time for no reason at all. Besides, if I created a project for every question I answered, I'd need a lot more disk space. Last, but not least, I am the one who decides if and how I'm going to help, since you're the one who needs help and I'm the one providing it. If you need a multi-file node-like online editor, use codesandbox.io

Comment: wow! thanks! one last thing, in the same method (getPeople) I can't get the "v-model" value that the user will write to do other things?
or I should create something else like: `@keypress=getNumberPeople(number)`

Comment: You have access to the v-model using `this.number`. `this` inside any method is your Vue instance. I used `event.target.value` as it might be different than `this.number` `@input` gets notified before the model value is actually changed (so that if you prevent it the `v-model` doesn't update). You can discard the assignment I made after `event.preventDefault()`. It's just common practice to provide a fallback normalizing value.

Comment: mythical!!! one last thing, and if I wanted instead of showing 999, make it stop writing? for example, I write 159, and by mistake I write 1599, it is annoying to see that 159 turn into 999 and have to rewrite ... I would really like that after the third digit do not write anything more!

Comment: Just use a `memory` variable. Updated the answer to include it. If you want other components to react to its changes, use a `Vue.observable()` instead. Or a `vuex` state prop.

Comment: But keep in mind  every time  `preventDefault()` is fired on `input` or `change` event the website is losing money (one way or another: visitors, sales, conversion rate, funneling percentage, etc...). And do like me, don't believe anyone else: do your own A/B testing.

Comment: Ref the `memory`. If you used `v-model` on a plain `<input>`, it wouldn't have been necessary. But because you're using `<b-form-input>` (a wrapper), the `v-model` has already changed, which is quite wrong. I would have expected the `v-model` update to happen in `$nextTick`, if `preventDefault()` has not been called, especially from a library as solid as BootstrapVue. Hopefully they'll get it right in their Vue 3 implementation.

Comment: unfortunately bootstrap vue has many flaws! and I'm discovering them using it .... if I knew it before I wouldn't have done it, I would have done everything by hand on my own ... they still have a long way to go!

Comment: You're not bound by it. Whenever it doesn't provide what I need, I simply replace their component with plain Bootstrap markup and my own events. But I find it useful and efficient in a lot of aspects, to be totally fair. In this example, nobody's stopping us from using a `<input>` with class `form-control`, managing the validation classes ourselves and, obviously, binding the `v-model` ourselves, right? It totally works. BV is just a set of shorthands. They don't provide a full vocabulary, but they cover a good chunk of cases.